# Why was my question regarding adventures containing a crashed spaceship "poor Q&A"?

Tags: discussion

In the comments to my question [Where to find an adventure with a crashed spaceship](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13110/where-to-find-an-adventure-with-a-crashed-spaceship) wax eagle noted that my question makes for poor Q&A.

I would like a clarification of what this means. To my understanding, resource and reference requests work fine on this sort of sites - at least MathOverflow accepts reference requests as suitable questions.

Or maybe I should make the question community wiki and for a list of adventures containing crashed spaceships?

Or was the question too specific?

---

I should note that I edited the original question, adding a list of features I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my opinion and people are welcome to disagree with it.

I think that this question was a poor fit for Q&A because its asking for a resource (considered a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)). My definition is a fairly narrow one and not necessarily shared by others on this site. My close vote is currently the only one so I'd wait until there are some more there to really start complaining (it takes 5 or a moderator to close a question).

While I think the subject matter is interesting I think the question as posed is poor. That's me, and my opinion, you (and the rest of the site) are welcome to disagree with it. There is some more information on asking subjective questions [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: My intention was not complain, and I did not even notice a vote to close.  The link to shopping questions helps to understand the inappropriateness, thanks.  I see I should not ask for, say, the best adventure of particular kind. However, thus far, I know of no adventure of the kind I am looking for, even after some googling and such.  This given, how should I alter the question to improve it, or is it simply unsuitable for the site?

Comment: @Thanuir not sure right off the top of my head how to save it. Hope on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/the-game-table) and we might figure something out.

Comment: No chat on this computer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Thanuir in that case I'd just leave the question alone. At the moment no one else seems to agree with me so I'd just leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that the question was fine but came close to a asking for a list of things.  It is hard to see what the best answer would be as well since you have not given really enough details as to what you were looking for.

Comment: Would asking for a list of things be inappropriate, then? I figure this community would be quite good at collecting lists of stuff, and compiling such would be useful. Further, the rating system would serve well to sort such a list.

Comment: @Thanuir We've had long drawn out discussions about that, and the general agreement is that they're dangerous, because they take no expertise, voting tends to be based on popularity, not quality, and to be honest, they often crowd out more meaty (ie: expertise requiring) questions.